# Drag and Drop in meteor

Tags: meteor, file-upload

I am trying to use drag and drop on background image in a div but nothing is working. I did not find any drag and drop module for image in meteor. Is there any module or any default function in meteor to drag a background image. After uploading image is coming in div background now i want that user can drag that image and can set it's position. This is my code where i am showing image in background after uploading.

```
<div id="edit-image" class="text-center {{page}} {{isIosDevices}} {{profileHeader}}" style="{{myCoverPicture}}">
                    {{> uploaderbg profileHeader="profileHeader" userProfile=this.profile fromProfile=true}}
                  </div>
```

======= Interact JS ==================

```
'click .text-center': function (e) {

    var isDraggable = interact('#test-img').draggable(); // true
}   

<div id="my-image" class="text-center" style="">
   <img src="{{myPicture}}" id="test-img" />
 </div>
```

=================================================

```
 Template.dragImgBg.onCreated(function helloOnCreated () {
  const instance = this;
  var ImageAxis1 = Meteor.user().profile.imageAxis;
  values=ImageAxis1.split(' ');

  instance.offsetx = new ReactiveVar(values[0]);
  instance.offsety = new ReactiveVar(values[1]);


  //console.log(ImageAxis1);
  // fixed in this example
  instance.bgUrl = new ReactiveVar(Meteor.user().profile.coverPicture);
})

Template.dragImgBg.helpers({
  offsetx() {
    return Template.instance().offsetx.get()
  },
  offsety() {
    return Template.instance().offsety.get()
  },
  bgUrl() {
    return Template.instance().bgUrl.get()
  }
})

let active = false

Template.dragImgBg.events({
  'mouseup' (/* event, templateInstance */) {
    active = false
  },
  'mouseout .img-bg-movable' (/* event, templateInstance */) {
    active = false
  },
  'mousedown .img-bg-movable' (/* event, templateInstance */) {
    active = true
  },
  'mousemove'(event, templateInstance) {

    if (!active) {
      return
    }
    const movementx = event.originalEvent.movementX;
    const movementy = event.originalEvent.movementY;

    const oldx = templateInstance.offsetx.get();
    const oldy = templateInstance.offsety.get();


    let data = $('#data_img_pos')[0]; 
    data.value = (oldx + movementx)+" "+(oldy + movementy);
    templateInstance.offsetx.set(oldx + movementx); 
    templateInstance.offsety.set(oldy + movementy);


  }
})



  <template name="dragImgBg">
    <div  id="edit-image" class="img-bg-movable bg-img text-center {{page}} {{isIosDevices}}" style="background-position: {{offsetx}}px {{offsety}}px;background-image: url({{bgUrl}});">
       {{> uploaderbg profileHeader="profileHeader" userProfile=this.profile fromProfile=true}}
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Try sortablejs: https://github.com/SortableJS/Sortable it works fine with Blaze (you need to setup in `onRendered`). If you get stuck please post the Template code here.

Comment: But in examples it's showing all examples for sortable. I need drag image feature like i have uploaded image on my profile page and then i can set it's position by dragging it

Comment: Think your images acting as the handle class (see the documentation about handles).

Comment: In my case there will be single image in as div background and i need drag so that user can set image position as profile banner image like facebook

Comment: Then you may rather look at `interactjs`

Comment: I need something like this https://www.scoopism.com/laravel/add-cover-image-like-facebook-adjust-position-image/ but in meteor

Comment: I have tried to use interact js but not able to drag image. Also updated above code with interact js

Comment: Did my answer helped you?

Comment: All things seems working fine but after drag and drop and saving values in DB i am trying to show position it's not working. I have updated code in above message. I am trying to pass x,y values in "Template.dragImgBg.onCreated" function. I am doing something wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After realizing, that this is not trivial in Blaze using third party libraries I tried to write some custom code.

Consider the following Template:

```html
<template name="dragImgBg">
    <div class="img-bg-movable" style="background-position: {{offsetx}}px {{offsety}}px;background-image: url({{bgUrl}});"></div>
</template>
```

with the following (examplatory) CSS:

```css
.img-bg-movable {
  width: 600px;
  height: 250px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: solid 1px #AAAAAA;
  cursor: grab;
}

.img-bg-movable:active:hover {
  cursor: grabbing;
}
```

As you can see the div is dynamically accepting styles, such as background image url (the one you get from your uploaded images) and x / y offset for the position.

The values for those styles are saved in reactive sources like a `ReactiveVar` and provided by simple helpers:

```js
Template.dragImgBg.onCreated(function helloOnCreated () {
  const instance = this
  instance.offsetx = new ReactiveVar(0)
  instance.offsety = new ReactiveVar(0)
  // fixed in this example
  instance.bgUrl = new ReactiveVar('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3f/Caldwell_68_Corona_Australis_Dark_Molecular_Cloud.jpg')
})

Template.dragImgBg.helpers({
  offsetx() {
    return Template.instance().offsetx.get()
  },
  offsety() {
    return Template.instance().offsety.get()
  },
  bgUrl() {
    return Template.instance().bgUrl.get()
  }
})
```

In order to change these values (and thus move the image) there needs to be some events that check, whether the element has been left-mouse-pressed and the mouse is moved.

If so, the delta values of the mouse-move are added to the reactive offset x / y sources. If the mouse is released or moved outside the image the values won't be applied.

```js
let active = false

Template.dragImgBg.events({
  'mouseup' (/* event, templateInstance */) {
    active = false
  },
  'mouseout .img-bg-movable' (/* event, templateInstance */) {
    active = false
  },
  'mousedown .img-bg-movable' (/* event, templateInstance */) {
    active = true
  },
  'mousemove'(event, templateInstance) {
    if (!active) {
      return
    }
    const movementx = event.originalEvent.movementX
    const movementy = event.originalEvent.movementY

    const oldx = templateInstance.offsetx.get()
    const oldy = templateInstance.offsety.get()

    templateInstance.offsetx.set(oldx + movementx)
    templateInstance.offsety.set(oldy + movementy)
  }
})
```

The `originalEevnt` refers to the original event that is wrapped by the Template's jQuery event. You may customize the Template your needs.

If you know for example the dimensions of the image you could stop updating the position of `offsetx` or `offsety` reach these boundaries.

If you want to make this persistent (like for a user profile page) you can save the values of `bgUrl` (or the image file id of the uploaded image) and the offset x / y values in a collection and load these vlaues in `onCreated`   's `autorun` routine.

Comment: All things seems working fine but after drag and drop and saving values in DB i am trying to show position it's not working. I have updated code in above message. I am trying to pass x,y values in "Template.dragImgBg.onCreated" function. I am doing something wrong here.

Comment: Are the values in ImageAxis1 defined when printing them?

Comment: yes x value is coming in values[0] and y in values[1]. It shows image on xy position but drag stops.

Comment: do you have any idea why it's creating issue?

Comment: In your example HTML code there is helper passing the axis to the `style` attribute. Did you just missed it? If not please look at the html in my answer.

Comment: i have passed html style attribute also. I have added html also in above code.